# Connecting chars and converting to string

Tags: c++, char, tostring

I want to connect to chars from char array , convert to string and display in console.
I don't know what i am doing wrong , i only get some weird letter on console.

```
char alpha[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
char sum;
stringstream ss;
string s;
sum = alpha[2] + alpha[3];
ss << sum;
ss >> s;
cout << s << endl;
system("pause");
```

Comment: `sum = alpha[2] + alpha[3];` doesn't do what you think it does. Try `s.append()` instead.

Comment: how to sum chars in c++? , i'm new in c :/

Comment: Do you want to sum or concatenate?

Comment: concatenate sorry for missleadning

Comment: Please edit the question (it is very unclear in its current form!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um.... A `std::string` can be constructed directly from any character array -- all you need to know are the begin and end characters.

```
char alpha[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
std::string s( alpha+2, 2 );  // start at index 2, length=2 characters
std::cout << s << "\n";
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do something along the following lines to concatenate `char` values in a `std::string`:

```
string s;
s.append(alpha[2]);
s.append(alpha[3]);

cout << s << endl;
```

---

Alternate solution using `std::stringstream`:

```
stringstream ss;
ss << alpha[2] << alpha[3];

cout << ss.str() << endl;
```